# Only one button in my javascript function when I want two

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, button

I am doing an assignment for class and attempting to make a javascript function with a button to show the value on a slider component. However, the function only shows one button when there should be two. I am passing two values in my array. I can't find the error. Any help would do.

DEMO.html

```
<div class="slidercomponent" id ="component1"></div> <br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <div class="slidercomponent" id ="component2"></div>


        <script type="text/javascript">

            var foodarray = [
                {
                    caption: "Tiramisu",
                    image: "https://food.fnr.sndimg.com/content/dam/images/food/fullset/2011/2/4/2/RX-FNM_030111-Sugar-Fix-005_s4x3.jpg.rend.hgtvcom.826.620.suffix/1371597326801.jpeg"
                },
                {
                    caption: "Blueberry Muffin",
                    image: "https://tmbidigitalassetsazure.blob.core.windows.net/rms3-prod/attachments/37/1200x1200/Wild-Blueberry-Muffins_EXPS_FTTMZ19_787_B03_05_7b_rms.jpg"
                }
            ];
            
            var component1 = MakeSliderFW(foodarray);
            document.getElementById("component1").appendChild(component1);
            var component2 = MakeSliderFW(foodarray);
            document.getElementById("component2").appendChild(component2);
        </script>
```

MakeSliderFW.js

```
function MakeSliderFW(list)
{
   
    var slider = document.createElement("div");

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var sliderElement = document.createElement("div");
        slider.appendChild(sliderElement);

        var container = document.createElement("div");
        container.classList.add("container");
        sliderElement.appendChild(container);
        
        var image = document.createElement("img");
        image.classList.add("resize");
        image.classList.add("image");
        image.src = list[i].image;
        container.appendChild(image);
        
        
        var overlay = document.createElement("div");
        var text = document.createElement("div");
        container.appendChild(overlay);

        var slidecontainer = document.createElement("div");
        slidecontainer.classList.add("slidecontainer");
        sliderElement.appendChild(slidecontainer);
        
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        var range;
        var rangee;
        input.type = "range";
        input.min = "1";
        input.max = "100";
        input.value = "50";
        input.classList.add("slider");
        
          input.oninput = function () {
           console.log("range = " + input.value);
           rangee = input.value;
        };

        input.onchange = function () {
           range = this.value;
           console.log("onchange =" + range);
        };
        
        slidecontainer.appendChild(input);

        
        var button = document.createElement("button");
        button.innerHTML = "Value";
        sliderElement.appendChild(button);
        
        var buttonOut = document.createElement("p");
        sliderElement.appendChild(buttonOut);

        button.onclick = function ()
        {
        
                    buttonOut.innerHTML = input.value;
                    console.log("buttonOut= " + buttonOut);
            
        };
        sliderElement.appendChild(buttonOut);
    }
    return slider;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is an image better demonstrating my issue.

[image: Current Situation]

Comment: There are some fundamental issues that you may also want to address: don't put script inline on a page, put it in its own .js file and then load that with `<script src="..." async defer></script>` so that it loads as soon as possible, but doesn't _run_ until the DOM has been constructed. Also, you only need `type` for a script element in HTML5 if it's _not_ JavaScript. Code wise, rather than `var` you really want to be using the modern `let` and `const`, both of which obey block scope. And don't use `<br>`: you already have `id` attributes: use a css file where you declare the margins for them

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans okay sounds good! I will definitely look into applying them. To be honest, a lot of this style of coding was taught by my teacher and I am just following her teachings. But I will definitely apply what you listed above

Comment: (also, rather than the legacy `onclick`, use normal modern event listening: `button.addEventListener("click", ...)`. If you've been learning from a tutorial, you want to start looking for a more modern tutorial: this code looks very out of date, and is not teaching you best practices. Try looking for something that teaches HTML5 with "ES6" javascript, or a versioned-by-year ES, like ES2016 or ES2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By replacing:

```
button.onclick = function ()
    {
    
                buttonOut.innerHTML = input.value;
                console.log("buttonOut= " + buttonOut);
        
    };
```

with:

```
button.onclick = function (input, buttonOut) {
                    return function() {
                        buttonOut.innerHTML = input.value;
                    }
                 }(input, buttonOut);
```

you will also get buttonOut under first picture. The problem is with the way you are setting your onclick function inside for loop. That way you will always get last loop value inside callback, which is obviously not desired effect.

Comment: Some heroes don't wear capes. Thank you